# How to have a trait method have a struct argument, in which an item must implement that same trait?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a struct `Lambertian`:

```rust
pub struct Lambertian {
    albedo: Color,
}
```

A `Material` trait with an associated method:

```rust
pub trait Material {
    fn scatter(&self, ray: &Ray, rec: &HitRecord) -> Option<(Ray, Color)>;
}
```

And finally, another struct that holds a value of something that implements the `Material` trait

```rust
pub struct HitRecord<T>
where T: Material
{
    // snip
    pub mat_ptr: Rc<T>,
}
```

So, I want the generic `T` in `HitRecord` to implement `Material`, but I have a parameter of type `HitRecord` in the trait method `scatter`. To make this work, I have to annotate `Material` with another `T`, then specifying that that T implements Material as well... Hence doing a recursive definition. What do I need to do instead ?

Comment: You can specify the type like `trait Material<T: Material<T>>`. But I'm unable to tell what you're trying to do, so I can't tell what you _should_ do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the generic on the `scatter` method rather than `Material`:

```
pub trait Material {
    fn scatter<T>(&self, ray: &Ray, rec: &HitRecord<T>) -> Option<(Ray, Color)>
    where
        T: Material;
}
```

---

Or if you want `rec` to use the same material type as `self`, make the generic argument `Self`:

```
pub trait Material {
    fn scatter(&self, ray: &Ray, rec: &HitRecord<Self>) -> Option<(Ray, Color)>;
}
```

This requires relaxing the constraint `Sized` constraint on `HitRecord<T>`:

```
pub struct HitRecord<T>
where
    T: Material + ?Sized,
```